# Struct/Class to Interface substitution contract broken?

Tags: c#, class, interface, substitution, contract

```
public interface IVector<TScalar> {
    void Add(ref IVector<TScalar> addend);
}

public struct Vector3f : IVector<float> {
    public void Add(ref Vector3f addend);
}
```

**Compiler answer:**

"`Vector3f` does not implement interface member `IVector<float>.Add(ref IVector<float>)`"

Comment: The contract is that it should accept *any* `IVector<float>`, not just your given implementation. C# does not support argument variance as a way of overriding methods or fulfilling interfaces.

Comment: Yeah, I've just realized it myself, TY anyway.

Answer (score 2):

But you can do this:

```
public interface IVector<T, TScalar>
    where T : IVector<T, TScalar>
{
    void Add(ref T addend);
}

public struct Vector3f : IVector<Vector3f, float>
{
    public void Add(ref Vector3f addend)
    {
    }
}
```

However, this means you've got mutable structs, which you shouldn't.  To have immutable ones, you'd need to redefine the interface:

```
public interface IVector<T, TScalar>
    where T : IVector<T, TScalar>
{
    T Add(T addend);
}

public struct Vector3f : IVector<Vector3f, float>
{
    public Vector3f Add(Vector3f addend)
    {
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As Anthony Pegram points out, there are holes in this pattern.  Nonetheless, it's widely used.  For example:

```
struct Int32 : IComparable<Int32> ...
```

For more information, here is a link to Eric Lippert's article [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) about this pattern.

Comment: However, given this, you could then also define `EvilVector3f : IVector<Vector3f, float>`, because there's still no* way of cleanly expressing the idea that an interface or abstract method be implemented in such as a way that it only works with the type of the class that implements it. (*that I know of, and I admit I'm an idiot.)

Comment: Agree, obviously this is wrong approach and is not what I'm looking for, since it does not separate interface from implementation.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram good point.  This is called the "curiously recurring template pattern" in C++, and should perhaps be called the "curiously recurring generic pattern" in C# but Google only gives 1390 hits for that phrase.  I've added a link to Eric Lippert's article on the subject.

Comment: @Haroogan in what way does it fail to separate interface from implementation?

Comment: Because you still have to explicitly specify the exact implementation in the interface - therefore I can't see any benefit from this "pattern" in this context.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: So what if someone did define an EvilVector3f.  What sort of havoc would they actually be able to wreak with it?  Note that IVector would probably be used as a constraint for types like `VectorList<T, U> where T : IVector<T, U>`, rather than a variable or parameter type.  The `VectorList` wouldn't accept `EvilVector3f` as a type parameter, and the `AppendItem` method of a `VectorList(Vector3f, float)` wouldn't accept an instance of `EvilVector3f` as an actual parameter.

Comment: @supercat, you're drawn to struct questions like a moth to a light! 1) I've already stated that I'm just the average idiot, I'm neither experienced nor creative enough to come up with sinister scenarios but, more than that, 2) the idea was that the type system simply can't be used to to limit the implementation in such a way. It becomes a matter of *trust* that it's used the way you intend. Along those lines, note that you're making assumptions on how the implementation would be used, which is safe so long as you're the one defining both the contract and the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted a difficulty with your interface, which is that there isn't any way to cleanly identify classes which can operate mutually with other items of their own class; this difficulty stems in some measure from the fact that such classes violate the Liskov Substitution Principle; if a class accepts two objects of type baseQ and expects to have one operate on each other, then the LSP would dictate that one should be able to replace one of the baseQ objects with a derivedQ.  This in turn implies that a baseQ should operate on a derivedQ, and a derivedQ should operate on a baseQ.  More broadly, any derivative of baseQ should operate on any other derivative of baseQ.  The interface is thus not covariant, nor contravariant, nor invariant, but rather non-generic.

If the reason one wishes to use generics is to allow one's interfaces to act upon structs without boxing, the pattern given in phoog's answer is a good one.  One generally shouldn't worry about imposing reflexive constraints on type parameters, since the purpose of the interfaces is to be used not as constraints, rather than variable or parameter types, and the necessary conditions can be imposed by the routine using the constraints (e.g. `VectorList<T,U> where T:IVector<T,U>`).

Incidentally, I should mention that the behavior of interface types used as constraints is very different from that of variables and parameters of interface type.  For every struct type, there is another type derived from ValueType; this latter type will exhibit reference semantics rather than value semantics.  If a variable or parameter of a value type is passed to a routine or stored in a variable that requires a class type, the system will copy the contents to a new class object derived from ValueType.  If the struct in question is immutable, any and all such copies will always hold the same content as the original and each other, and may thus be regarded as being generally semantically equivalent to the original.  If, however, the struct in question is mutable, such copying operations may yield semantics very different from what might be expected.  While there are times it can be useful to have interface methods mutate structs, such interfaces must be used with extreme care.

For example, consider the behavior of `List<T>.Enumerator`, which implements `IEnumerator<T>`.  Copying one variable of type `List<T>.Enumerator` to another of that same type will take a "snapshot" of the list position; calling MoveNext on one variable will not affect the other.  Copying such a variable to one of type `Object`, `IEnumerator<T>`, or an interface derived from `IEnumerator<T>`, will also take a shapshot, and as above calling MoveNext on either the original or the new variable will leave the other unaffected.  On the other hand, copying one variable of type `Object`, `IEnumerator<T>`, or an interface derived from `IEnumerator<T>` to another which is also one of those types (same or different), will not take a snapshot, but simply copy a reference to the earlier-created snapshot.

There are times it can be useful to have all copies of a variable be semantically equivalent.  There are other times it can be useful for them to be semantically detached.  Unfortunately, if one isn't careful, one may end up with an odd mish-mosh of semantics which could only be described as "semantically confusing".